# Failed to set the initialPlaybackTime for a MPMoviePlayerController when recreating it in the second time

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, playback

When at the first time a MPMoviePlayerController (e.g., theMovie) is created, its initialPlaybackTime can be set successfully. But when theMoive is released and re-create a new MPMoviePlayerController, its intialPlaybackTime can not be set correctly, actually the movie always plays from the start. The code is as follows.

```
-(void)initAndPlayMovie:(NSURL *)movieURL
{

    MPMoviePlayerController *theMovie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];

    // create a notification for moviePlaybackFinish
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:theMovie];

    theMovie.initialPlaybackTime = 15;
    [theMovie setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill];
    [theMovie play];}
-(void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    MPMoviePlayerController * theMovie = [notification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:theMovie];
    [theMovie release];
    [self initAndPlayMovie:[self getMovieURL]];
}
```

With the above code, when the viewcontroller did load and run initAndPlayMovie, the movie starts to play from 15 seconds, but when it plays finished or "Done" is pushed, a new theMovie is created and starts to play from 0 second. Does anybody know what happened with the initialPlaybackTime property of MPMoviePlayerController?

And whenever you reload the viewController where the above code is (presentModalViewController from a parent viewcontroller), the movie can start from any playback time. I am really confused what's the difference of the MPMoviePlayerController registration methods between the viewcontroller load and the recreating it after release.

Comment: [Your question has been answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548492/why-is-it-not-possible-to-use-the-mpmovieplayercontroller-more-than-once)

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been resolved!
It needs one step to make the initialPlaybackTime setting properly.

after release the movieplayer, 1-second delay is needed before starting play again. Make sure the movieplayer is released completely.

It took me 3 days to figure out the issue. But now my question is how I can detect if a movieplayer has been released completely rather than to wait for one second.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by a "complete" release and how is it different from `[player release], player = nil;`?

Answer (score 1):

After you have released your theMovie, give it a value nil

`[theMovie released];
theMovie = nil;`

then you can tell if it released already.

`if (theMovie == nil){ 

    //do something here when movie player is released already

}`