# iOS - Playing more than one video

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, video, video-streaming

I am using this code with the MediaPlayer framework to play a video:

```
-(void)GrommeVideoExcerpt1
{
NSURL *url1 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                     pathForResource:@"GrommeVideoExcerpt1" ofType:@"mp4"]];
grommePlayer1 =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                  initWithContentURL:url1];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:grommePlayer1];

grommePlayer1.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
grommePlayer1.shouldAutoplay = YES;
[self.view addSubview:grommePlayer1.view];
[grommePlayer1 setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
}
```

But when I play one video, then navigate to another video and try to play it, the app crashes. It gives me this error:

http://pastebin.com/nUGLXEAi

Comment: Could you please add your `moviePlayBackDidFinish:` method.

Comment: In the tutorial I followed there was no method like that, how would I implement this?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548492/why-is-it-not-possible-to-use-the-mpmovieplayercontroller-more-than-once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is you are adding a notification for when the video finishes playing, and that notification triggers a method you do not have (`moviePlayBackDidFinish:`) causing the crash.

You could implement this method or remove the notification, depends what you want to do after the video is done playing i.e. remove a viewController that plays the video, etc.

```
//Register notification
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                     selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                         name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                       object:nil];
//Then the method ...
-(void) moviePlaybackDidFinish:(NSNotification *)aNotification{
  [grommePlayer1.view removeFromSuperview];
  grommePlayer1 = nil;
}
```

Comment: I want to go back to the previous view when it is done playing the video, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Updated my answer, hope it helps.